# Internet Explorer 8 - Magento and Simple configurable products wrong product and price not being updated

Tags: magento, internet-explorer-8, magento-1.5, configurable-product

We're using Magento Simple Configurable products extension with Magento 1.6.0 to get the price of child products on the configurable products page. ie the price of the simple product should be used for each combination of products rather than using the configurable products price +/- a % or amount.

However, using Internet Explorer 8, when you select an option from the drop down list, the price is updated to "£0.00". If you then add this product to the shopping cart, it is added at the price of the lowest item and not the correct price for the simple product you have chosen.Have been over and through google search and github with no luck thus far.

Have tried the solution suggestion at https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/issues/14 by removing the "_clone" designation, but all this does is keep the price fixed on the display page at the lowest price for all browsers, but the same product is added to the cart on the Buy now submission (i.e. wrong product for IE8, correct for all other browsers).

An example of this happening is at http://www.atlantisrugs.com/modern-chinese-arctic-rug-19 - any/all help appreciated!